# log4net with asp.net mvc - can't watch file for changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, powershell, log4net

So in a console .Net application I can watch all my log4net events stream by with (the powershell command) `get-content .\log.log -Wait` which is similar to the linux `tail` command and I assume uses FileSystemWatcher under the hood.

For some reason, whenever I have an asp.net Mvc application this will not work. To be clear, the log file IS written to. I can `get-content .\log.log` as many times as I want and get the most recent results, but with the `-wait` parameter I never see the changes scroll past.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** found a working solution for my case, not sure whether this would help you out.

Instead of using PowerShell, I downloaded [win-bash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/) and now I'm using this familiar Unix command which works perfectly for me.

```
tail -f access.log
```

I'm not that familiar with .Net programming. Could it be a working solution in your case to use win-bash project's bash.exe instead of PowerShell?

---

I am experiencing similar issue when trying to "tail" Apache access log in PowerShell.

```
Get-Content .\access.log -Wait
```

I noticed that when my Apache HTTP server is running, it has a handle open to acccess.log and -Wait doesn't work. Stopping HTTP server releases the handle and when I made manual changes to access.log using text editor my PowerShell window immediately reflected changes in the console.

So I assume if some other program has a handle open to the file, changes are not reflected to console. Unfortunately I haven't found a way around this issue so far.

Comment: I DO think that the issue is with file locking but my concern was more that log4net should not be doing that at all! I was hoping more for a configuration setting which would release that lock. As an aside, why pick win-bash over cygwin?

Comment: I have used cygwin before, but now I didn't have cygwin installed and win-bash seemed quick and easy enough. Just downloaded and started using bash.exe whereas cygwin would have required installation. In case I happen to need more Unix-like environment, I'll probably ditch win-bash and start using cygwin again.